# Start windows with no wallpaper, start bar and desktop icons

Tags: windows, batch-file

Im using a computer with windows 7 as a digital signage system, all i need to do is to start an app (exe), Id like to disable the start menu, the desktop icons and even replace the wallpaper with a black image, i can do this manually but i will like to have a batch script to this for me, but dont know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands directly or from a batch file at an elevated command prompt:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v Shell /d "Drive:\Path to\My app.exe" /f
shutdown /f /r /t 0
```

(Obviously you need to edit the first command to specify the full path to your app.)